# How to assign values from current matrix to another an empty matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

Currently, i would like do a loop function whereas it could copy the current existing data from myMatric matrix to another new matrix named as centroid. Below are my snippet code in R:

```
x<-c(1,2,4,5)
y<-c(1,1,3,4)
myMatric<-matrix(cbind(x,y), ncol=2)

test<-function(myMatrix,k)
{
  centroid<-matrix(nrow=k, ncol=2)
  for(i in 1:nrow(myMatric))
  {
    for(j in 1:ncol(myMatric))
    {
      centroid[i,j]<- myMatric[i,j]
      # first time printing data from centroid
      print(centroid[i,j]) 
    }
  }
}


test(myMatric,k=2)
# second time printing data from centroid
print(centroid)
```

When i call the first print centroid function, i looks like working well and display the value as below:

```
 > testKmeans(myMatric,k=2)
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 1
```

However, when i tried to print the centroid value, all were became NA as below:

```
> print(centroid)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA
```

Could anyone here show me the right step to copy value from current matrix to another matrix, then able to call back current result from the copied matrix.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why not `matrix2 <- matrix1`?

Comment: you're having a *scoping* problem.  You either need to return the value of `centroid` from the function or (much less preferred) use the `<<-` global assignment operator.  I also get `Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, j, value = 4) : subscript out of bounds` when I run your function, and `Error in print(centroid) : object 'centroid' not found` when I try `print(centroid)` ...

Comment: Thank you Richard Scriven..but sometime i do not want to copy all and need to identify element in the specific row and column

Comment: Thank you Ben Bolker..i got the same Error statement..but still do not know how to overcome the issue